# I want to use and update a Slick carousel when I click nav bar dropdown items?

Tags: html, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

I am using Slick carousel and it works. Now I have a nav bar with dropdown menu and I am not sure how I can show a certain slides when I click the most nested level - in this case celebrity - here is my html code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

  <title>CSS Dropdown Menu</title>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Portrait</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Human</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="" data-category="celebrity">Celebrity</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#" data-category="unknown">Unknown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Car</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Full body</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Human</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" data-category="celebrity">Celebrity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-category="unknown">Unknown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Car</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Naturalistic group</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Human</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" data-category="celebrity">Celebrity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-category="unknown">Unknown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Car</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Posed group</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Human</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" data-category="celebrity">Celebrity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-category="unknown">Unknown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Car</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
 
  </nav>

  <div class="slick-carousel">
    <div data-category="celebrity">
      <img src="https://images1.penguinrandomhouse.com/author/22627" alt="...">
      <p>Image Caption</p>
    </div>
    <div data-category="celebrity">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1701308450512-d3a2aeeff787?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDI3NjE5MDB8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85" alt="caption">
      <p>Image Caption</p>
    </div>
    <!-- More carousel items -->
  </div>

  <!--   <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and this is my css:

```
    body,
div,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
ol,
li,
dl,
dt,
dd,
img,
form,
fieldset,
input,
textarea,
blockquote {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #909eab url(bg.png);
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

nav {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #efefef;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  background: #5f6975;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  z-index: 2;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 25px;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 25px;
}

.slick-carousel p {
  margin-top: 8px; /* Space between image and caption */
  color: #c71d1d; /* Caption text color */
  /* Additional styling as needed */
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-carousel div {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

and here is the script:

```
    import slickCarousel from "https://esm.sh/slick-carousel";
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".slick-carousel").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true
  });

  $("nav ul li ul li ul li a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // Get the category from the link text

    // Filter carousel items based on the category
    $(".slick-carousel").slick("slickUnfilter"); // Remove any previous filters
    $(".slick-carousel").slick("slickFilter", function () {
      return $(this).data("category") === category;
    });
  });
});
```

However, I cannot make it work and nothing happens when I click on `celebrity` in the first nested menu. And the two images are still shown at the bottom of the page instead of showing up when I click `celebrity`. How should I change my codes to be able to update slides when I click menu items? Appreciate any help.